# Want to loop through all tables in sql DB & perform some operation on the record which contain current datetime in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am stuck at a point where i need to go through all the tables in DB and perform some query on the record which get match to current datetime(datetime is previously stored in tables as enddate).

so i have number of tables in my DB which tables have names like `'%_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS'`, starting of each table is `username`
**ex:** if username is john then table name is john_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS.

I want to loop through all these tables & get those records which match `enddate` to `current date`. The records which match `enddate` to `current datetime` will be updated & same record get inserted in another `xyz` table. i want to put this querfory in event so it keep checking all tables after particular time interval that if some record hits endtime. someone please guide me with code.

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql-Server? those are 2 different products.

Comment: Also you will need to show some sample schema of those different dates involved with some examples

Comment: it is sql server 2008

Comment: i found this query but what it returns is table names that i need.    SELECT o.name AS TableName FROM sys.objects AS o where o.name like '%_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS' 
 how can entar in each table & check each record to current datetime & perform some operations on each which match current datetime

Comment: there is column enddate in each '%_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS' table which contain enddate in 6/15/2016 2:19:06 PM this format. just want to compare current date to this one and if both make match need to perform some operations on that corresponding record.

Comment: You will have to use dynamic sql (or, if possible, you better refactor your database and unite all these tables to a single table and add a column for user name (or id)).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough details for me to give a full answer. One way to do it is to do something like this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
'
DECLARE @DateTimeToSearch datetime = GETDATE()

IF ''?'' LIKE ''%_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS%''
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ? WHERE enddate = @DateTimeToSearch
END
'
```

`sp_MSforeachtable` loops over all the tables in the database. The table's name is replaced by the placeholder `?`.

Comment: it seems to be worked but suddenly after run it search all tables and display errors like    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'date_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'date_time'.
Why it is so???? date_time column present in these tables with datetime datatype.