# need to loop through all table in DB & fire some query where condition get matched

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using sql server 2008. i want to loop through all tables in DB with specific names & want to update only those records where enddatetime column data match to current date and time. enddatetime column present in all tables. after serching on net i come across this code but i unable to modify it for update query. please someone guide me with correct code?

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
'
DECLARE @DateTimeToSearch datetime = GETDATE()

IF ''?'' LIKE ''%_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS%''
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM ? WHERE enddate = @DateTimeToSearch
END
'
```

Comment: Another option is to create your query dynamically inside the stored procedure to update just some of the tables and not all:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: [... "searching on net", eh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787517/want-to-loop-through-all-tables-in-sql-db-perform-some-operation-on-the-record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For table names with matching strings use below query

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
'

IF ''?'' LIKE ''%yourtablename%''
BEGIN
Update ? set col1 = value where enddatetime = Getdate()
END'
```

For specific list of tables use the below query

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
'

IF ''?'' in ( ''[schema-name1].[table-name1]'',''[schema-name2].[table-name2]'')
BEGIN
 Update ? set col1 = value where enddatetime = Getdate()
END'
```

Comment: I tried the code For table names with matching strings use which you provided but it encounter an error is:    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'enddate'..     for every table column where the condition has to be checked.

Comment: share the query you ran. check your table for column named "status". You are referring to column which is not there in the table. Check in all tables which have name matching with your table name

Comment: EXEC sp_MSforeachtable
    '

    IF ''?'' LIKE ''%_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS%''
    BEGIN
    Update ? set action = ''donez'' where status = ''Order_Created''
    END'

Comment: this is the query i ran. columns are correctly present in tables.

Comment: there must be table with name containing string "_PHGH_LINK_DETAILS" and which doesn't have stauts column. Look for it. You can use second version of the query in case number of tables is less